# display (print) sorted list python (not using list.sort)

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x, input

Practicing with functions I created a function to sort a list of numbers (Python 3.x):

```
def insertion_sort(list):
    for index in range(1, len(list)):
        value = list[index]
        i = index -1
        while i >= 0:
            if value < list[i]:
                list[i+1] = list[i]
                list[i] = value
                i = i - 1
            else:
                break
```

using the python interpreter I get this:

```
>>> a = [5,3,7,9,1,8,6,2,4]
>>> insertion_sort(a)
>>> print(a)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

this function works well if used in the python interpreter but I wanted to do more and use the input method to 'ask' for the numbers so I did this...

```
a = input("Enter a list of numbers separated by a comma: ")
c = set(a)
b = []
b.append(c)
insertion_sort(b)
print (b)
```

when I run the code and enter the numbers `537918624` I get this:

```
[{'8', '9', '2', '3', '1', '6', '7', '4', '5'}]
```

Why won't it sort it and how can I make it print the list without the quotation marks?

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code before posting the question? What is the value of `a` then? What is the value of `c`? What is the value of `b` before running your sorting method? Maybe the problem is not with sorting and displaying it, but rather with parsing the input. Then you should change the title of the question (and tags) accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotation marks show that you have strings, not integers, in your set. `input` will always give you a string; you can convert strings to integers using `int()`.

Also, you are giving the sorting function a list with a single item inside, the `set`. Sorting a list with a single item in doesn't make any sense.

I would approach this as follows:

```
ui = input(...) # take input e.g. "1, 2, 3"
numbers = list(map(int, ui.split(","))) # turn to list of ints [1, 2, 3]
insertion_sort(numbers) # sort the list
```

There is no need to use a `set` - if there are duplicate numbers your sort algorithm should be able to manage this.

Your input didn't have commas in - I am assuming that (per the prompt!) the user should really be entering e.g. `5,3,79,...`.

Finally, note that you should not call the argument to `insertion_sort` `list`, as this shadows the built-in.